# NHibernate + Decimal + Precision x Scale

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following problem, when I try to write to the database by NHibernate a decimal field it is always writing with the precision x scale of (7.5) being that I need it to be in the precision x scale of (11, 8). I've tried several things and I can not.

Database column

```
longitude DECIMAL (11, 8);
```

Mapping field

```
<property name="Longitude">
    <column name="Longitude" sql-type="decimal" length="11" precision="8"  />
</property>
```

Class property

```
public virtual decimal Longitude { get; set; }
```

In the bank is recording like this,

> -11.22222000

being that I need it to be recorded as

> -11.22222333

Comment: Camilo Terevinto , I translated the question into English.

Answer (score 0):

I  find out what it was, was an NHIBERNATE 3.0 update. made the Decimal Precision Standard become 5, so it was necessary to change the mapping as the code below.

```
<property name="Longitude" type="decimal(11,8)">
      <column name="Longitude" sql-type="decimal" length="11" precision="8"  />
</property>
```